# How to import "gleam" package in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, graph, scatter-plot

I'm tyring to import the "gleam" package in Python 3. I have installed the "gleam" package successfully, but still it showing error.

```
from wtforms import fields
from ggplot import *

from gleam import Page, panels

class ScatterInput(panels.Inputs):
    title = fields.StringField(label="Title of plot:")
    yvar = fields.SelectField(label="Y axis",
                              choices=[("beef", "Beef"),
                                       ("pork", "Pork")])
    smoother = fields.BooleanField(label="Smoothing Curve")

class ScatterPlot(panels.Plot):
    name = "Scatter"

    def plot(self, inputs):
        p = ggplot(meat, aes(x='date', y=inputs.yvar))
        if inputs.smoother:
            p = p + stat_smooth(color="blue")
        p = p + geom_point() + ggtitle(inputs.title)
        return p

class ScatterPage(Page):
    input = ScatterInput()
    output = ScatterPlot()

 ScatterPage.run()
```

> Error:
>
> ModuleNotFoundError  -     Traceback (most> recent call last)  in ()
>
> ```
> ----> 1 import gleam
> ```
>
> C:\pythonNJ\lib\site-packages\gleam__init__.py in ()
>
> ```
>   5 import os
>   6 import json
> ```
>
> `----> 7 import urlparse`
>
> ```
>   8 from collections import namedtuple
>   9
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

I looked for the solution and I found that urlparse has been moved to a new module in python 3, which can be imported as

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

And I even imported it, but still when I trying to import "gleam" package it shows error of module "urlparse". Can you suggest me how to bypass it (bypassing import urlparse statement and importing gleam package in Python 3).
I know how to import the urlparse but I don't know how to import the gleam package.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possiblities:

1. Modify source code yourself as you stated inside `gleam` package, but it could work incorrectly.
2. Fall back to version of python it works on - so 2.7 it seems, since the modification you mentioned was done with python 3.0 release. It's stated in docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=urlparse#library-changes).

Comment: Thanks Shan, I'll try doing with modifying the `gleam` package.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to get over it:

from:

```
import urlparser
```

to:

```
import urllib.parse
```